# Xamarin non- string types not binding to label in release mode. Works as it should in Debug

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having problems binding a decimal value to a label in my listview. Everything is working as it should on Android, the only problem is with IOS in Release Mode (works ok in Debug).

I have tried creating an IValueConvertor:

```
public class DecimalConvertor:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = (decimal)value;
        return s.ToString();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = value as string;
        return decimal.Parse(s);
    }

}
```

When binding the value i use:

```
storeDistance1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,new Binding("Distance", BindingMode.OneWay, new DecimalConvertor()));
```

I have also tried:

```
storeDistance1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,new Binding("Distance", stringFormat:"{0}"));
```

But no luck, please could someone help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*************Update****************

I have found a solution to my problem.

I added binding context to my listview and selected all the fields that will be populated in my listview within the binding context as follows:

```
listView.BindingContext = stores.Select(s => new {s.Distance, s.Allow_Delivery, s.StoreUrl, s.StoreName, s.StoreAddress});
```

I also added the labels within my listview cell into a new stack layout (StoreDetail), and then added the new stacklayout into the children of the stacklayout which is binded to my view as follows.

```
var test = new StackLayout
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        webImage,
                        storeDetail, //a new stack layout containing all labels that are being binded 
                        collectionLbl,
                        deliveryLbl,
                        orderNowBtn
                    },
                    Padding = new Thickness(10, 20, 10, 20),
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Black
                };

                return new ViewCell()
                {
                    View = test
                };
```